# How to log game objects colliding in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first unity project so I am fairly unfamiliar with everything the platform has. I am trying to log a message to the console when I have a my player game object run into a finish line. Both objects have Box Colliders on them and I have attached a C# script to the player object. Below is the code I have currently.

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
     if (col.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
    {
        Debug.Log("Finish");


    }
}
```

The problem is that when I move the player into the "Finish" object no logging appears inside the console.
Thanks in Advance!

[This is the main player inspector tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trsEN.png)

[This is the finish line inspector tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Hom.png)

Comment: Have you verified the tag?

Comment: What happens when you debug it?

Comment: Does the player have a Rigidbody?

Comment: The player has a ridgidbody

Comment: Remove the condition and print the tag, object, and whatever else you can get your hands on

Comment: Show Inspector tab screenshot of the object.

Comment: I added the screenshots to the original question

Answer (score 3):

Your script attached to the player checks for a collision with an object with the tag "Finish". Your Object "Finish Line" has tag "untagged". You have to add a tag "Finish" to it to see it working.

Comment: @tflores you should mark this as answered, if it solved your problem. So others know as well.

Answer (score 2):

With the updated question and screenshots, the problem is that you're checking for the *"Finish"* tag but the *"Finish"* GameObject's tag is set to "Untagged" so the `if (col.gameObject.tag == "Finish")` statement will **not** evaluate to true.

*You have **two** options:*

**1**. Select the  "Finish" GameObject, click the tag that says "Untagged" and create new tag named "Finish". If you already have this tag, change the tag of the "Finish" GameObject from "Untagged" to  "Finish" and your `if (col.gameObject.tag == "Finish")` code should work.

---

**2**. If you did not intend to use tag then just compare the GameObject by name instead of tag by simply replacing `if (col.gameObject.tag == "Finish")` with `if (col.gameObject.name == "Finish")`.

If none of the two options above worked for you then `OnCollisionEnter2D` is not being called at-all. Put a `Debug.Log` outside the `if` statement like below and leave a comment about if there is a log or not.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("Finish: " + col.gameObject.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just first idea that came in mind:
- Did you add colliders on both of objects that should collide?
Without them engine will not generate events of colliding at all.

Comment: Yes they both have colliders, when I move the one object into the other, it will "bounce off" each other as well. But I do not receive a log message saying they have hit each other.